Initialize language from local storage on app startup with Riverpod Async Notifier Provider
I implemented localization with an option to select a language in the app and save it to the local storage.
When the app starts, I want to load the language from the storage to the MaterialApp.router to choose the preferred locale. I store the language choice in the Riverpod Async Notifier Provider, so the app refreshes if the user selects another language.
My current way of loading the language works, but it doesn't feel right. I use URL-based routing with GoRouter. I tried to implement initialization like shown in this tutorial, but since I watch currentLanguageProvider in the App widget, the of currentLanguageProvider is accessed before it has a value and I can't use the Child widget method.
Here is my minimal code:
/// app.dart

class App extends ConsumerWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final goRouter = ref.watch(goRouterProvider);
    final language = ref.watch(currentLanguageProvider).asData?.value;
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: goRouter,
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales, 
      locale: language != null ? Locale(language.code) : null,
    );
  }
}

/// current_language_provider.dart

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class CurrentLanguage extends _$CurrentLanguage {
  Future<LanguageEnum> _getLanguage() async {
    return await ref.read(getLanguageProvider.future);
  }

  @override
  FutureOr<LanguageEnum> build() async {
    return await _getLanguage();
  }

  void set(LanguageEnum value) {
    state = AsyncValue.data(value);
  }
}

Language repository is used to get and set preferred langugage in the memory (I use Secure Storage becuase I store other things there as well).
/// language_repository.dart
class LanguageRepository {
  final Ref ref;

  LanguageRepository(this.ref);

  final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  /// Method to store the language in the secure storage
  Future<void> setLanguage(LanguageEnum language) async {
    await storage.write(key: 'language', value: language.code);
    ref.read(currentLanguageProvider.notifier).set(language);
  }

  /// Method to get the language from the secure storage
  Future<LanguageEnum> getLanguage() async {
    final code = await storage.read(key: 'language');
    // If the language is not set, return the default language and set it in the secure storage
    if (code == null) {
      const defaultLanguage = LanguageEnum.eng;
      await setLanguage(defaultLanguage);
      return defaultLanguage;
    }
    for (var value in LanguageEnum.values) {
      if (value.code == code) {
        ref.read(currentLanguageProvider.notifier).set(value);
        return value;
      }
    }
    return LanguageEnum.eng;
  }
}

// Riverpod provider for the language repository
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
LanguageRepository languageRepository(LanguageRepositoryRef ref) {
  return LanguageRepository(ref);
}

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Future<LanguageEnum> getLanguage(GetLanguageRef ref) {
  return ref.read(languageRepositoryProvider).getLanguage();
}

The side drawer with a dropdown to choose a language:
/// side_drawer.dart
class SideDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Consumer(builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
              final language = ref.watch(currentLanguageProvider);
              return AsyncValueWidget(
                value: language,
                data: (currentLanguage) => DropdownButton(
                  value: currentLanguage,
                  items: [
                    for (var eachLanguage in LanguageEnum.values)
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: eachLanguage,
                        child: Text(eachLanguage.name),
                      ),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (value) async {
                    if (value != null) {
                      await ref.read(localizationControllerProvider.notifier).setLanguage(value);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              );
                }),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And a controller to set the values
@riverpod
class LocalizationController extends _$LocalizationController {
  @override
  FutureOr<void> build() async {
    return;
  }

  Future<void> setLanguage(LanguageEnum language) async {
    final languageRepo = ref.read(languageRepositoryProvider);
    await languageRepo.setLanguage(language);
  }
}

How could I improve this, so the language is loaded from the storage first, and when App widget is rendered, the currentLanguageRepository already has the value?
I don't want to use override method for the provider, since it's not recommended anymore.
